# Connect to remote socket via sshfs

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, ssh, sshfs

I want to make remote connection via socket pipe (`mysql.sock`) on remote server, which is mounted to directory using `sshfs`. But I experience some problems. Here's an example:

I have 2 servers. One of them is mysql server behind NAT (but ssh port is opened). So I can't directly open an mysql connection by:

`mysql -h mysql-server -u root -p`

I tried mount **mysql-server** using sshfs:

`sshfs user@mysql-server:/ ~/db`

Remote `mysql.sock` file in now located under:
`~/db/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

but after calling:

`mysql --socket=~/db/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock -u root -p`

I got:

`Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '~/db/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)`

`bind-address` is not present in config file.

---

So the question is: How to connect to remote socket in directory mounted through ssh?

OR

Is there any possibility to connect to remote mysql using ssh (all others ports are closed)? I need it to use with php later...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that is going to work... [Sockets are not supported over sshfs](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-803770-start-0.html) according to the sshfs developers.

Why aren't you just forwarding the MySQL TCP port over your SSH tunnel?

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@mysql-server
mysql localhost ...
```